# Why is the plural of "root locus" (in robotics) "root loci", when, in Latin, the plural of "locus" (place) is "loca"?

Tags: plural-forms, etymology

I've been reading about robotics in English recently, and I've seen quite a few times that the plural of "root locus" is "root loci". Why is that? In Latin, the plural of "locus" (place, location) is "loca".

Comment: Locus can be loci or loca in the nominative plural: see https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/locus#Latin and  https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/loci#Latin; see also this answer on the Latin stack exchange: https://latin.stackexchange.com/questions/2132/where-do-the-plurals-of-locus-come-from

Comment: And why are database indexes not indices?

Comment: @DrMoishePippik That's not the same thing. "Indexes" is the expected English plural, much like "locuses" would be. "Indices" would require an explanation, and in that case the explanation would be Latin. "Loci" also requires an explanation.

Comment: @FlatAssembler, the issue is that *both* "indices" and "indexes" are used in English... depending on the context. "One common language, I'm afraid we'll never get."

Comment: I've added the "etymology" tag to this question. Such questions aren't prohibited here, but [the tag's description](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/etymology) says "Please consider asking this question on English Language & Usage (http://english.stackexchange.com/) instead", and [this site's help pages](https://ell.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) suggest the same.

Answer (score 1):

This seems to be a generalization in English on the model of Latin second-declension stems. *Octopi* is not the plural of *Octopus* in Latin or Greek. *Cakctī* is however the plural of *cactus*. Although plural -s is generally allowable, something like *hippopotamusses is not euphonic and *hippos* sounds better.

Locus is a second declension stem, but could be confused with genitive singular *locī* and also dative plural *locīs*. In that case, *root locī* may mean the root to the locus, but mixing Latin and English within Noun Phrases like that is too unfashionable to be common. Also note that where the plural nominative is variable *locī, loca*, this behaviour is similar to Coptic ⲏ /æ/, /ɑ/, /ɪ/, which points to either to a very wide eclesiastic dialect continuum or a very unstable vowel in this position. Remember, Seth MacFarlane makes a joke of *programme* pronounced Brittish but hypercorrect /prōʹgrăm'ɪ/; implying that *locī* should become something like * †louke* or *low-key* according sound changes.